# R bigmemory won't read large csv file

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I'm trying to load in a 689.4 MB csv using `read.big.matrix` from the R `biganalytics` package in a similar way to the [Vignette for bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/vignettes/Overview.pdf).

Vignette Code:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(biganalytics)
x <- read.big.matrix("airline.csv", type="integer", header=TRUE,
        backingfile="airline.bin",
        descriptorfile="airline.desc",
        extraCols="Age")
```

Per the comment from 42-, I removed the factor variables using cut on the command line `cut -d, -f9,11,17,18,23 --complement 2008.csv > 2008cut.csv`

I then removed any of the NA values found in the data using sed `sed -i 's/NA/0/g' 2008cut.csv`  Even with those pre-processing steps, I receive the same error.

My code:

```
#This works
x <- read.csv("~/Downloads/2008cut.csv",header=T)
dim(y)
#[1] 7009728      29
length(complete.cases(x))
#[1] 7009728

library(bigmemory)
library(biganalytics)
#This errors out
data <- read.big.matrix("~/Downloads/2008cut.csv", 
            type="integer", header=TRUE)
```

I receive the following error when trying to run read.big.matrix:

```
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 31 then 32
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 28 then 29
Warning: stack imbalance in '-', 23 then 24
Warning: stack imbalance in '-', 22 then 23
Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 20 then 21
Error in big.matrix(nrow = numRows, ncol = createCols, type = type,
 dimnames = list(rowNames,  : 
    A big.matrix must have at least one row and one column
```

I have found others having this problem but they had [mixed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725603/reading-big-data-in-r-by-read-big-matrix) or a [similar problem](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-May/312404.html) but no response.  At some point in my search, someone on a mailing list asked if the user could run something like `x <- big.matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=10)` to make sure bigmemory was working in general.  I **am** able to run that code and generate a big.matrix.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Software Details:

- Data: [2008 File](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html)
- R: 3.2.3
- OS: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- bigmemory: 4.5.19
- biganalytics: 1.1.14

Comment: Is your problem a matter of memory limit or are you just trying to improve the speed of reading `.csv` file ?

Comment: The documentation of the file structure on the linked page suggests that choosing "integer" for that file would not succeed. Some of the columns are clearly not integers.

Comment: @RafaelPereira I'm trying to better understand the bigmemory library and its applications.  I'm working with 32 GB of RAM so the file fits in memory but I want to explore the data under the bigmemory framework.
@42- Good point.  I originally tried this with an amazon file.  Even after removing the factor variables using `cut -d, -f9,11,17,18,23 --complement 2008.csv > 2008cut.csv` I received the same error :-\

Comment: `read.big.matrix` is in `bigmemory` and not `biganalytics`.  Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this, it works without a problem on my linux (Ubuntu 14.04) box.  Perhaps you can file an [issue](https://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigmemory/issues) with the other developers and they may have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

For reading large files, I suggest to use the `fread` from R `data.table` package.

Comment: This does not address the question, does it ?

Comment: Looks like the resulting table works with tools like biglm but not bigkmeans.  fread seems to loads the entire file into memory, whereas bigmemory will store pointers in memory instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path:

```
absolutePath <- normalizePath("~/Downloads/2008cut.csv")

x <- read.big.matrix(absolutePath, type="integer", header=TRUE,
        backingfile="airline.bin",
        descriptorfile="airline.desc",
        extraCols="Age")
```