# Loading an 11 GB .csv file as a big.matrix object

Tags: r, csv, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I have a 11GB .csv file which I would ultimately need as a `big.matrix` object. From what I have read I think I need to create a filebacked `big.matrix` object but I cannot figure out how to do this.

The file is too large for me to load directly into R and manipulate from there as I have done with smaller datasets. How do I produce a `big.matrix` object from the .csv file?

Comment: Is it a sparse matrix?

Comment: @RuiBarradas  yes there are mostly zeros

Comment: Is the object indeed a matrix? In other words, are all columns of the same type?

Comment: @socialscientist yes all columns hold integer values

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `data.table()` solution? 11GB should be fine for it. `slam` is also good.

Comment: @socialscientist could I convert this later into a big.matrix object? I am happy to do intermediary steps but I need to use the data in the biglasso package which only accepts big.matrix objects unfortunately

Comment: Ah, in that case just need `read.big.matrix` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigmemory/versions/4.4.6/topics/write.big.matrix%2C%20read.big.matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading big data in R by read.big.matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725603/reading-big-data-in-r-by-read-big-matrix)

Comment: @socialscientist yes I think using read.big.matrix will be the right way to go... I dont know how to make the backingfile or the descriptorfile? Are these separate files I need to create and save to my laptop or are they made by the function and I just have to give a name ?

Comment: @socialscientist thank you for editing my post ! It is definitely a lot clearer now, much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at https://privefl.github.io/bigstatsr/articles/read-FBM-from-file.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this can be of help. I post as an answer because it contains too much code for a comment.

The strategy is to read chunks of 10K rows at a time and coerce them to a sparse matrix. Then, `rbind` those sub-matrices together.
It uses `data.table::fread` for speed and a function in package `fpeek` to count the number of lines in the data file. This function is also fast.

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)

flname <- "your_filename"
nlines <- fpeek::peek_count_lines(flname)
chunk <- 10*1024

passes <- nlines %/% chunk
remaining <- nlines %% chunk
skip <- 0

data_list <- vector("list", length = passes + (remaining > 0))
for(i in seq_len(passes)) {
  tmp <- fread(flname, sep = ",", colClasses = "double", skip = skip, nrows = chunk)
  data_list[[i]] <- Matrix(as.matrix(tmp), sparse = TRUE)
  skip <- skip + chunk
}
if(remaining > 0) {
  tmp <- fread(flname, sep = ",", colClasses = "double", skip = skip)
  data_list[[passes + 1L]] <- Matrix(as.matrix(tmp), sparse = TRUE)
}

sparse_mat <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
rm(data_list)
```

---

## Test data

With the following test data all went alright. I also tried it with a bigger matrix.

The `path` is optional.

```
path <- "~/Temp"
flname <- file.path(path, "big_example.csv")
a <- matrix(1:(25*1024), ncol = 1)
b <- matrix(rbinom(25*1024*10, size = 1, prob = 0.01), ncol = 10)
a <- cbind(a, b)
dim(a)
write.csv(a, fl, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Might as well add an example file to demonstrate it doing what the OP wants, e.g. `write.csv(c(1:100000), "big_example.csv")`. I think the OP wants a `big.matrix` though to pass to the other `bigmemory` functions. Would need (anonymous, possibly) file-backing though presumably?

Comment: @socialscientist Done. If the OP's matrix is sparse, like it is said in comment, then a sparse matrix might solve the problem skipping the file-backed operations. Maybe.